# WP_Query duplicate post

Tags: wordpress

I used wp_query in my wordpress theme. 
I have duplicate post an my houme page.
How this to fix? With what this problem can be connected?

The whole paradox is that if you use this code as a separate template, then everything works. And if you embed themes in a module, then all posts go in order. And then again (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5).

Thanks.

```
}

function render() {
    ob_start();
    ?>               
           <?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page= 1');
             while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
                    ?>
              <div class="post-1">
                <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">          
                  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </h3>    
                     <div class="float-tags">          
                                    <div class="bb-td-post-small-box clearfix">        
                                      <?php the_tags('','',''); ?>
                                    </div>
                     </div>
                  <div class="post-2">                                            
                    <?php the_content(); ?>    
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>  

             <?php endwhile; ?>  
             <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>


    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
}
```

Comment: So you have duplicate data in you database?

Comment: Duplicate post an my houmepage, look screenshot

Comment: Can you please send screenshot of your admin dashboard [post listing and page listing] section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function render($offset,$posts_per_page) 
{
    ob_start();
    $args['offset']=$offset;
    $args['posts_per_page']= $posts_per_page;
    $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();

?>
              <div class="post-1">
                <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">          
                  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </h3>    
                     <div class="float-tags">          
                                    <div class="bb-td-post-small-box clearfix">        
                                      <?php the_tags('','',''); ?>
                                    </div>
                     </div>
                  <div class="post-2">                                            
                    <?php the_content(); ?>    
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>  

             <?php endwhile; ?>  
             <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>


    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
render(0,5); //shows first 5,  0 to 5
render(5,5); //shows second 5,  5 to 10
render(5,5); //shows third 5,  10 to 15
```

Comment: Blank page, only header and footer. The whole paradox is that if you use this code as a separate template, then everything works. And if you embed themes in a module, then all posts go in order. And then again (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: @Ivan I am really sorry that I am unable to understand this comment.

Comment: If you use this code, there are no posts on the page.

Comment: Just Remove the line " ob_start();" and "return ob_get_clean(); " you will get the result. I just tested the code and working if removed.

Comment: You can say your mail, I'll write you login and pass.

Comment: tristup@gmail.com

Comment: I just replied to you

Answer (score 1):

In this way you will always get the one post which will repeat no.of times you called the **render** function in your code. If you want that to show the different posts each time then you must specify the offset of the posts in **WP_QUERY**.
REF : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query [ Offset ]
NOTE : Act like limit in PHP.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Can more details, please? I do not quite understand.

Comment: If I do  'posts_per_page= 5'  , then 5 posts are displayed, then again 5 posts displayed.

Comment: See, you need give the start index for next time, it will take 0 as start index and showing 5 posts from 0th. you need to change it next time, like 0+5=5 someting like that

Comment: check the next answer